# Rewrite all subdomains to HTTPS With A Few Twists

Tags: .htaccess

I scoured the digital realm trying to find a solution for this because it has to be a common scenario but, alas, I failed.  I didn't want to paste my MULTIPLE ITERATIONS of HTACCESS blurbs.  I promise, I exhausted the lot.

Short version:  Forward all subdomains to HTTPS.  If no subdomain is specified, forward to HTTPS WWW.

Detailed Version:

if http or https, if there is no subdomain, forward to https www.

i.e.  http://example.com OR https://example.com

would **forward** to

https://www.example.com

if there IS a subdomain, then forward to the HTTPS for that subdomain.

i.e. http://www.example.com

would forward to
  https://www.example.com

and any subdomain, same behavior
 i.e.  content.example.com 
 would forward to

https://content.example.com

Answer (score 3):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```